# How to show GNOME power preferences in Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xfce4-power-manager

I installed `gnome-power-manager` and removed `xfce4-power-manager` in my netbook.

But the Power Preferences is not showing in the Xubuntu Control Center. I want to show this config application:
[image]

How can I show it? (gnome-power-preferences is not exist in Trusty).

Thanks in advance!